# MySQL ORDER BY clause slowing query by 4x

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, where-clause

UPDATE: I have vastly simplified the calls below and made adjustments to the question.

I'm trying to figure out how to make this query faster.

My query retrieves person/communication information for individuals in a specific campaign (in this example, 4). I join the most recent communication and sort by the communication date_created value. Below is the SQL we use.

Note I'm doing LEFT JOIN because only a handful of people may have conversations associated with them; I still want to return matching people based on the core select (e.g. if 5 people have conversations but there's 30 people, I still want to show all 30, but sorted by those with conversations, and by date on those conversations).

Below is the FAST call that is only 350ms to execute; the problem is it's the equivalent of an INNER JOIN due to the AND clause and thus doesn't LEFT JOIN the person_main records.

```
SELECT *
    FROM person_main pm
    LEFT JOIN cms_conversation_member ccmem ON ccmem.member_object_record_id = pm.ID   
        AND ccmem.member_type_c = get_gcs('cms_conversation_member', 'member_type_c', 'internal')
        AND ccmem.member_object_type_sc = get_gss('OBJECT_BASE','PERSON')
        AND ccmem.member_object_subtype_sc = get_gss('OBJECT_PERSON','MAIN')
    LEFT JOIN cms_conversation_main convm ON convm.ID = ccmem.cms_conversation_main_ref_id
    LEFT JOIN cms_communication_main ccomm ON ccomm.cms_conversation_main_ref_id = convm.ID
        AND ccomm.comm_direction_c = get_gcs('cms_communication_main', 'comm_direction_c', 'incoming')
    WHERE 1 = 1       
    GROUP BY pm.ID
    ORDER BY ccomm.date_created
    LIMIT 0,30;
```

Here is the SQL EXPLAIN of the call

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "select_type": "PRIMARY",
        "table": "ci",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "UK_campaign_item",
        "key": "UK_campaign_item",
        "key_len": "6",
        "ref": "const,const,const",
        "rows": "1000",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "select_type": "PRIMARY",
        "table": "pm",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,ID_UNIQUE,IDX_person_main_name_first,IDX_person_main_name_middle,IDX_person_main_name_last,IDX_person_main_name_nick",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "4",
        "ref": "xxx.ci.item_object_ref_id",
        "rows": "1",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "null"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "select_type": "PRIMARY",
        "table": "ccomm",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,UK_cms_communication_main_ID",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "4",
        "ref": "func",
        "rows": "1",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "select_type": "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",
        "table": "ccomm2",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "index",
        "possible_keys": "FK_cms_communication_main_cms_conversation_main_ref_id,IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_direction_c",
        "key": "IDX_cms_communication_main_date_created",
        "key_len": "5",
        "ref": "null",
        "rows": "2",
        "filtered": "40.0",
        "Extra": "Using where; Backward index scan"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "select_type": "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",
        "table": "<subquery3>",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "<auto_distinct_key>",
        "key": "<auto_distinct_key>",
        "key_len": "6",
        "ref": "xxx.ccomm2.cms_conversation_main_ref_id,xxx.pm.ID",
        "rows": "1",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "select_type": "MATERIALIZED",
        "table": "ccmem",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "IDX_cms_conversation_member,IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_type_c,FK_cms_conversation_member_cms_conversation_main_ref_id",
        "key": "IDX_cms_conversation_member",
        "key_len": "6",
        "ref": "const,const,xxx.pm.ID",
        "rows": "3",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using where"
    }
]
```

Here is the call that returns all records (even people without communication), but it takes 2.4 seconds (6x slower than the above call). **But this is the resulting data that I need.**

```
    SELECT *
    FROM person_main pm
    LEFT JOIN cms_conversation_member ccmem ON ccmem.member_object_record_id = pm.ID   
        AND ccmem.member_type_c = get_gcs('cms_conversation_member', 'member_type_c', 'internal')
        AND ccmem.member_object_type_sc = get_gss('OBJECT_BASE','PERSON')
        AND ccmem.member_object_subtype_sc = get_gss('OBJECT_PERSON','MAIN')
    LEFT JOIN cms_conversation_main convm ON convm.ID = ccmem.cms_conversation_main_ref_id
    LEFT JOIN cms_communication_main ccomm ON ccomm.cms_conversation_main_ref_id = convm.ID
        AND ccomm.comm_direction_c = get_gcs('cms_communication_main', 'comm_direction_c', 'incoming')
    WHERE 1 = 1       
    GROUP BY pm.ID
    ORDER BY ccomm.date_created
    LIMIT 0,30;
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for the above call:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "select_type": "PRIMARY",
        "table": "ci",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "UK_campaign_item",
        "key": "UK_campaign_item",
        "key_len": "6",
        "ref": "const,const,const",
        "rows": "1000",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "select_type": "PRIMARY",
        "table": "pm",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,ID_UNIQUE,IDX_person_main_name_first,IDX_person_main_name_middle,IDX_person_main_name_last,IDX_person_main_name_nick",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "4",
        "ref": "xxx.ci.item_object_ref_id",
        "rows": "1",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "null"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "select_type": "PRIMARY",
        "table": "ccomm",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,UK_cms_communication_main_ID",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "4",
        "ref": "func",
        "rows": "1",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "select_type": "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",
        "table": "ccomm2",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "index",
        "possible_keys": "FK_cms_communication_main_cms_conversation_main_ref_id,IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_direction_c",
        "key": "IDX_cms_communication_main_date_created",
        "key_len": "5",
        "ref": "null",
        "rows": "2",
        "filtered": "40.0",
        "Extra": "Using where; Backward index scan"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "select_type": "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",
        "table": "<subquery3>",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "<auto_distinct_key>",
        "key": "<auto_distinct_key>",
        "key_len": "6",
        "ref": "xxx.ccomm2.cms_conversation_main_ref_id,xxx.pm.ID",
        "rows": "1",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "select_type": "MATERIALIZED",
        "table": "ccmem",
        "partitions": "null",
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "IDX_cms_conversation_member,IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_type_c,FK_cms_conversation_member_cms_conversation_main_ref_id",
        "key": "IDX_cms_conversation_member",
        "key_len": "6",
        "ref": "const,const,xxx.pm.ID",
        "rows": "3",
        "filtered": "100.0",
        "Extra": "Using where"
    }
]
```

Here are the Table Creation scripts.

**cms_communication_main**

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';

--
-- Create table `cms_communication_main`
--
CREATE TABLE cms_communication_main (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date_created datetime NOT NULL,
    comm_id_external varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    comm_platform_c smallint NOT NULL,
    comm_direction_c tinyint NOT NULL,
    comm_state_sc smallint NOT NULL,
    comm_timestamp datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    comm_details json DEFAULT NULL,
    cms_conversation_main_ref_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX UK_cms_communication_main_ID (ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 3276,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_communication_main_date_created` on table `cms_communication_main`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_communication_main
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_communication_main_date_created (date_created);

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_platform_c` on table `cms_communication_main`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_communication_main
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_platform_c (comm_platform_c);

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_direction_c` on table `cms_communication_main`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_communication_main
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_direction_c (comm_direction_c);

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_id_external` on table `cms_communication_main`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_communication_main
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX IDX_cms_communication_main_comm_id_external (comm_id_external);

--
-- Create foreign key
--
ALTER TABLE cms_communication_main
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_cms_communication_main_cms_conversation_main_ref_id FOREIGN KEY (cms_conversation_main_ref_id)
REFERENCES cms_conversation_main (ID);
```

**cms_conversation_main**

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';

CREATE TABLE cms_conversation_main (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date_created datetime NOT NULL,
    conversation_type_c smallint NOT NULL,
    conversation_id_external varchar(995) DEFAULT '',
    owner_account_main_ref_id int NOT NULL,
    conversation_state_sc smallint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX UK_cms_conversation_main_ID (ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 47,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_conversation_main_date_created` on table `cms_conversation_main`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_main
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_conversation_main_date_created (date_created);

--
-- Create foreign key
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_main
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_cms_conversation_main_owner_account_main_ref_id FOREIGN KEY (owner_account_main_ref_id)
REFERENCES account_main (ID);
```

**cms_conversation_member**

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';

CREATE TABLE cms_conversation_member (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date_joined datetime NOT NULL,
    member_type_c smallint NOT NULL,
    member_originator tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    member_object_type_sc smallint NOT NULL,
    member_object_subtype_sc smallint NOT NULL,
    member_object_record_id smallint NOT NULL,
    member_custom_id varchar(995) DEFAULT NULL,
    member_communication_key varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    cms_conversation_main_ref_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX UK_cms_conversation_member_ID (ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 11,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 50,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_conversation_member_date_joined` on table `cms_conversation_member`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_member
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_conversation_member_date_joined (date_joined);

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_conversation_member` on table `cms_conversation_member`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_member
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_conversation_member (member_object_type_sc, member_object_subtype_sc, member_object_record_id);

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_type_c` on table `cms_conversation_member`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_member
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_type_c (member_type_c);

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_originator` on table `cms_conversation_member`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_member
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_originator (member_originator);

--
-- Create index `IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_communication_key` on table `cms_conversation_member`
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_member
ADD INDEX IDX_cms_conversation_member_member_communication_key (member_communication_key);

--
-- Create foreign key
--
ALTER TABLE cms_conversation_member
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_cms_conversation_member_cms_conversation_main_ref_id FOREIGN KEY (cms_conversation_main_ref_id)
REFERENCES cms_conversation_main (ID);
```

Any idea why the second call takes 5-6x longer than the first? Why is MySQL "lagging" so much on left joins that don't match the communications from the person_main table?

Comment: please edit your question to add (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables in the query and output of `explain SELECT rest-of-your-statement` with and without the order by

Comment: is the speed without the order by you mention with or without the limit?  if with, how many rows would there be without the limit and does removing the limit also make it slow?

Comment: @ysth I added the SQL Explain. I'd prefer not to bloat it with the table creations; but I can say all of the referenced fields are Indexed.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info). We really do need your table definitions.

Comment: @O.Jones understood and updated.

Comment: I'll take a look. At first glance, it looks like there may be some opportunities for better performance. And you do have the notorious  `SELECT mess of columns FROM ... JOIN ... ORDER BY something LIMIT 0, 30` performance anti pattern.

Comment: You have a complex nest of [correlated subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html), and I'm having trouble untangling it. Correlated subqueries can be performance killers. Do you have a recent MySQL or MariaDB version? If so you can use [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to write your queries more succinctly. I suggest you try to rewrite the query without correlated subqueries, and then assess your performance again.

Comment: Updated core example code to refine and simplify.

Comment: @O.Jones thank you for your response - please note I updated the post with even more simplified calls. I examined applying CTEs, but I don't think that's feasible as I'm making a list from the root person ID and the CMS tables can have hundreds of thousands (or more) of records; hence the matching. The core issue is the calls are 4 layers deep - person>member>conversation>communication. But please note the updated details I posted are very interesting - the core call (which is essentially an inner join) is ultra fast, but an equivalent left join call is 5-6x slower...

Comment: Replacing the get_gcs() calls with the actual values (e.g. 5, 6, 12) speeds up the query 10x. This tells me the functions are not being handled as DETERMINISTIC even though they area. All they do is look up and fetch a value from a table - same value every time. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: @Floobinator - The query seems to be updated; but not the Explain.  `"table": "ci"` disappeared.  Please edit to get things in sync.

Answer (score 0):

- What is `get_gcs()`?
- If it is a Stored Function, is it `DETERMINISTIC`?
- Try to use a `JOIN` instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  (It seems that the `IN (... campaign_item ci ...)` has already been turned into a `JOIN` (see the first row of the `EXPLAIN`).
- Tentative indexes:

  ```
    ccomm:  INDEX(ID,  date_created)
    cms_conversation_member:  INDEX(member_type_c, member_object_type_sc,
       member_object_subtype_sc, member_object_record_id,  cms_conversation_main_ref_id)
    cms_communication_main:  INDEX(cms_conversation_main_ref_id,
       comm_direction_c, date_created,  ID)
    ci:  INDEX(campaign_main_ref_id, item_object_type_sc,
       item_object_subtype_sc, item_object_ref_id)
  ```
- Are you sure you want `LEFT JOIN`, not simply `INNER JOIN`?  After all, the query seems to expect values for this:  `ORDER BY  ccomm.date_created`.
- You may not need the `GROUP BY`.  If you do, then you can probably still get rid of it by turning the query inside-out.
- Time the subqueries (with some value filled in for `pm.ID`).  The goal is to decide whether one of them is the main performance bottleneck.
- `PRIMARY,ID_UNIQUE` -- This seems to imply that you have `PRIMARY KEY(ID), UNIQUE(ID)`.  If so, be aware that a PK is a Unique key.  Hence the `UNIQUE(ID)` is redundant.

Comment: yes, it seems like nearly every condition is wrapped in a function, which means he's going to be bypassing just about all of those indexes, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland - There are hints that `get_gss('constant', 'constant')` is constant.  That is, it seems to be pre-evaluated.  Hence, `column = get_gss(...)` _can_ an index on `column`.

Comment: Actually, I guess as long as you aren't applying the function to the column itself then it will be fine.  I just saw (what looked like) some column names in the function calls and misread it.  On second look I suppose as long as you are doing `WHERE get_gss(col, arg) = condition` then it will be fine.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland - First part is correct.  `fcn(col)` is not "sargable", hence the index is not useful.  Last part is not sargable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rick, but unfortunately it doesn't help me. Note I've updated the core example code to refine and simplify the problem.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland how do we get a function return value usable with an Index? DETERMINISTIC isn't enough?